# Exception java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, foreach, mapper

While working around following code I got the exception given below.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> obj = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

for (Map<String, Object> map : obj) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : "+entry.getKey()+" Value is: "+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? The first one? Have you tried replacing `new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){}` with `new TypeReference<List<Map<String,Object>>>(){}`?

Comment: @BorisPavlović, Yes I tried it now and I am getting exception telling: 
 Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at  [Source: {"total":1,"movies":[{"id":"771390242","title":"Deadpool"}]

Comment: Use `Map<String, Object> obj = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});`

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use only a Map instead of List of Map.

```
 Map<String, Object> object = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
 for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : object.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("Key : "+entry.getKey()+" Value is:"+entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This : Are you trying to Store MapObject in List.so instead of Map store in List.

instead of:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> obj = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(),
new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
```

Use This :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> obj = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), 
new TypeReference<List<Map<String,Object>>>(){});
```

For Demo example [This Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: Hey @Benjamin, I tried it. After trying that I got this error:
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: {"total":1,"movies":[{"id":"771390242","title":"Deadpool"}]